Robocyl path following using costmap
I have to design a ROS node that receives a reference path toward a global goal position and generates command velocities to safely follow it while avoiding sensed obstacles. This can be achieved using the robot’s scan measurements, pose, goal pose, the occupancy grid of the environment, a navigation costmap, and available coordinate transformations (i.e., tf).
I already have the costmap, the occupancy grid and I have a path to the goal position. However, I am having trouble with implementing an algorithm that uses the path to generate the linear and angular velocities required to navigate to a goal position at the end of the path.
The picture is how my set up looks like, with the purple line on the picture to the right being the path itself.

Do you need to write code or just define an algorithm? Are you familiar with the components of the ros2 navigation stack?

I need to write code. As for the navigation stack, I am not familiar with it. It did show up a couple of times when looking for a solution on google, but I wasn't too sure if it would work for my usecase. I've added some extra info to my post for more context.
